# How many non-isomorphic groups share the same character table?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

I have been thinking for a while about how to [enumerate all finite groups](https://oeis.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_order_n). The classical way e.g. [here](https://www.worldcat.org/title/enumeration-of-finite-groups/oclc/154682311) would be to go via latin squares and then try to calculate how many of those obey associativity. That turns out to be a major problem, and there are only estimations (an asymptotic approximation in the oder) known to date.

An idea would be to construct the groups from their representations in the hope that things will turn out easier there. A possible program would be first to generate all permissible irreducible representations, then character tables, and then see how many groups share one character table.

This is of course a monstrous program (as also the enumeration of groups is), but I just recently became aware of this work about [Finite groups with the same character tables, Drinfel’d algebras and Galois algebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0001119.pdf) from A. A. Davydov. Unfortunately I am not able to understand it with my current knowlegde, so I wanted to ask if anyone who might understand could estimate if this work can lead to an answer to the question of

> > For finite groups, how many non-isomorphic groups share the same character table?

Comment: I don't really understand the question.There can be an arbitrarily large number of distinct finite groups with the same character table.

Comment: @DerekHolt presumably "How many" is not a literal enumeration question, but rather "Can one characterize such finite groups". It seems like the linked paper provides a complete solution, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Of course, you forgot to use the word "non-isomorphic".

Comment: That paper references some older papers where questions of groups sharing character tables are discussed. Maybe some of those older papers would be easier to understand.

Comment: A complete determination of groups admitting equivalent tensor categories (but not preserving the symmetry of the tensor product, as that implies they're isomorphic), is [in this paper of Etingof and Gelaki](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0007196). Existence of such non-isomorphic groups is tied into the existence of certain normal 2-subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt So you think there is an infinite number of groups of order 1?

Comment: @Rudi_Birnbaum Mathematical truths are not a matter of opinion, but they often reduce to definitions, and abuse of notation and language is common amongsts mathematicians. Group theorists habitually refer to groups as being different or distinct when they really mean non-isomorphic, which is fine as long as everyone knows what they are talking about.  So to answer your question, yes, strictly speaking there is an infinite number of distinct groups of order one, but most group theorists would assert that there is only one.

Comment: Just in case you really misunderstood my previous comment, I meant that for any positive integer $N$, there exists an integer $n$ such that there are at least $N$ non-isomorphic groups of order $n$ with the same character table. And I honestly don't think that this is a good approach to the problem of enumerating all finite groups.

Comment: If you are interested in enumerating all groups of given order, take a look here: http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/grpconst.html. -- As Derek Holt already said, going via character tables is hardly a good approach.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Oh quite interesting, does that lead to an explicit formula? _at_Derek Holt: I indeed missunderstood your first post, though I do not see how that would mean anything for the basic idea. Anyway I appreciate personal expert opinions. And I dont "believe" in absolute truths (not even in maths). In the end its always that one thinks its an absolute truth. Max Born has a nice quote on that "The belief that there is only one truth, and that oneself is in possession of it, is the root of all evil in the world.”

Comment: @Rudi_Birnbaum : To expect any kind of explicit formula is wildly optimistic. If you're just starting to think about this problem then I suggest taking a look at the references here http://oeis.org/A000679 to get some sense of the difficulties. As for your question, you need to pose it more carefully. Maybe you are looking for an efficient algorithm to compute all (non-isomorphic) finite groups with a given character table? In that case you might want to look at G. Higman's paper "Construction of simple groups from character tables" as a starting point.